# Creating operating system (OS) user in Oracle LINUX

Tags: linux, users, mysql, useradd

I am a user with sudo access. To install MySQL, I have to create an operating system (OS) user  called MySQL. Can I create a user which also has sudo access on this machine?

Comment: Do not give the mysql user sudo access. If you read somewhere that you should do it, you probably misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

The [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-installation.html) way to create the mysql account is:

```
groupadd mysql
useradd -r -g mysql mysql
```

Add the `-m` option if you want that account to be used as a login account, which looks to be the case.

If you have full `sudo` access, you can grant `sudo` rights to that use with using

```
sudo visudo
```

and adding a line similar the one starting with your username and replacing your username with `mysql`.

Comment: Does Operating system user and root user ( or user with sudo access) are same?

Comment: Operating System user is just used here to distinguish the account from a database account which is defined in a mysql table. An OS user is defined in /etc/passwd, a shared directory or similar.

Comment: root is a special OS user account with unlimited rights.